# How to get the same information for all templates?

Tags: html, django, jinja2, django-2.1

So in Django, i have a base template which has some contact details in it. but every view that i generate i have to have the line.

```
contact = Contact.objects.first()
```

Then i have to add that object to the dictionary that's loaded with the template.

What is the better way to deal with is? I find it hard to believe that i'm doing it in the correct way.

Examaple views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from services.models import Service, ServicesDetail
from .models import Feature, CompanyDetail, TeamMember, TeamDetail, Banner
from contact.models import ContactDetail
import json

# Create your views here.
def home(request):
    services = Service.objects
    try:
        overview = ServicesDetail.objects.first()
    except ServicesDetail.DoesNotExist:
        overview = ''
    try:
        company = CompanyDetail.objects.first()
    except CompanyDetail.DoesNotExist:
        company = ''

    features = Feature.objects

    contact_details = ContactDetail.objects.first()

    banners = Banner.objects
    return render(request, 'home.html', {'overview': overview,
                                         'services': services,
                                         'company': company,
                                         'features': features,
                                         'contact_detail': contact_details,
                                         'banners': banners})

def company(request):
    services = Service.objects
    try:
        company = CompanyDetail.objects.first()
    except CompanyDetail.DoesNotExist:
        company = ''

    features = Feature.objects
    contact_details = ContactDetail.objects.first()
    return render(request, 'company.html', {'services': services,
                                            'company': company,
                                            'features': features,
                                            'contact_detail': contact_details,})

def team(request):
    services = Service.objects
    members = TeamMember.objects
    try:
        teampage = TeamDetail.objects.first()
    except TeamDetail.DoesNotExist:
        teampage = ''
    contact_details = ContactDetail.objects.first()
    return render(request, 'team.html', {'services': services,
                                         'members': members,
                                         'teampage': teampage,
                                         'contact_detail': contact_details,})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can switch to [class base template views](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/class-based-views/base/#django.views.generic.base.TemplateView) and write your custom base class

```
class MyBaseTemplateView(TemplateView):
    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['contact_details'] = ContactDetail.objects.first()
        return context


class MyActualView(MyBaseTemplateView):
    template_name = 'company.html'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        # set other specific context values for this view here
        return context
```

and add these views to your `urls.py` like this:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', MyActualView.as_view(), name='myactualview'),
]
```

Comment: I like this idea the best. but my base template is in a different sub dir. What views should i put the base template class in. or does it go in all views?

Comment: it's not important to be in a sub dir, just import it. no it doesn't go with all of your views, you should use this base template for views needing `contact_details`

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to do it in each view, just write custom [context processor](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/templates/api/#writing-your-own-context-processors):

```
def contact_details(request):
    return {'contact_detail': contact_details = ContactDetail.objects.first()}
```

And add it to `TEMPLATES` setting:

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
                'path.to.processor.contact_details'
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

Comment: i just used this method on a different project. works relly really well, thank you so much